# Strange behaviour using OpenLayers + Mapguide Layer

Tags: openlayers, mapguide

I'm trying to use a Mapguide Layer with OpenLayers.
First of all, I've used code taken from the official [example page](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mapguide.html).
All works fine, the map is showed and I can zoom it.
But, if I move the map (pan), the map recenter automatically on the initial center.

I've used exactly the same code as the example page mentioned above. 
It's something missed with my mapguide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.

By default, OpenLayers doesn't had support to EPSG:3003.
Despite this, when I do { projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3003") } in the code, no errors raise.

I've fixed this adding proj4js library and definition for EPSG:3003.

Hope this help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

This URL below is working (openlayer + mapguide).
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/mapguide-untiled.html?q=mapguide